Capturing Display Media Streams with headless browser (puppeteer) (navigator not defined)
im trying to create web conference application with node-js (express) as backend, and i need to record those conferences on the server, so one solution was using a headless browser like puppetteer and join each conference with it and capture the screen media streams, but i found out the navigator is undefined on my headless page, is there any workaround for this? and if there is none can anyone with experience give me a solution for recording these conferences on server? its gonna be WebRTC app (not sure yet but most likely SFU with "Kurento")
